# Spring WebClient ExchangeFilterFunction is running again after next.exchange()

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, webclient

I have a WebClient implementantion with some logs ands "Trace" implementation, in this code I add some header in my req and wait for end.

The implementation works without error, but after `next.exchange()`, my filter is executed again:

My client builder:

```
private final WebClient.Builder builder;

builder
    .baseUrl(url)
    .filter(new GenericAwsXrayHandler(url))
    .build();
```

and my filter:

```
public class GenericAwsXrayHandler implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

  private final String url;

  public GenericAwsXrayHandler(final String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(final ClientRequest request, final ExchangeFunction next) {

    log.info("executing filter");

    final Subsegment subsegment = AWSXRay.getGlobalRecorder().beginSubsegment(url);
    final TraceHeader header = getTraceHeader(request, subsegment);

    final ClientRequest clientRequest =
        ClientRequest.from(request)
            .header(TraceHeader.HEADER_KEY, header.toString())
            .build();

    logRequest(clientRequest);

    return next
        .exchange(clientRequest)
        .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> {
          logResponse(clientResponse);
          addResponseInformation(subsegment, clientResponse);              
        })
        .doOnError(ex -> {
          subsegment.setFault(true);
          subsegment.addException(ex);
        })
        .doFinally(x -> {
          AWSXRay.getGlobalRecorder().endSubsegment(subsegment);
        });
  }
```

My output log:

```
2021/07/21 08:33:21.101  [main] [INFO ] b.c.i.o.r.a.o.p.h.h.GenericAwsXrayHandler - executing filter
2021/07/21 08:33:21.108  [main] [INFO ] b.c.i.o.r.a.o.p.h.h.GenericAwsXrayHandler - executing filter
```

Debugging, I see the filter running again just after `return next.exchange(clientRequest)`.

Did I missed something?

Comment: Is it possible that the filter is being added twice to your web client builder? You should be able to inspect the `filters` field in your`WebClient.Builder` instance.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen after your message, I did some debug and I see the problem: I left Spring Inject My WebClient Builder in a constructor, when this happens, for some reason, the filter is already in the chain and will be added again :(